# How to retry transaction after exception in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, exception, stored-procedures, rollback, savepoints

In different parts of my code I have to retry transactions after exceptions. But I cant figure out how to do it.
Here is my test function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    user_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE id < 50 limit 10;
    row RECORD;
    counter INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    dummy INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
    RAISE INFO 'Start... ';
    OPEN user_cur;
    LOOP
      FETCH user_cur INTO row;
      EXIT WHEN row IS NULL;

      BEGIN
        UPDATE "user" SET dummy = 'dummy' WHERE id = row.id;
        counter := counter + 1;
        dummy := 10 / (5 % counter);
        RAISE NOTICE 'dummy % , user_id %', (5 % counter), row.id;

      EXCEPTION WHEN division_by_zero THEN
          --What should I do here to retry transaction?
      END;
    END LOOP;
    RAISE INFO 'Finished.';

    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Why not put a check in to avoid the condition or handle return the exception to the code that's calling this?

Comment: The transaction is not aborted when the exception block is encountered, only the database changes up to the BEGIN above. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Comment: I know it =) I need something like GOTO to execute `UPDATE "user" SET dummy = 'dummy' WHERE id = row.id;` once more again, in current iteration with current row.id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the above comments I've found the solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    row RECORD;
    counter INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    dummy INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
    -- Clear user rating
    RAISE INFO 'Start... ';
    FOR row IN SELECT * FROM user_prop WHERE id < 50 limit 10 LOOP
      LOOP
        BEGIN
          UPDATE user_prop SET some_field = 'whatever' WHERE id = row.id;
          counter := counter + 1;
          dummy := 10 / (5 % counter);

          -- exit nested loop if no exception
          EXIT; 

        EXCEPTION 
          WHEN division_by_zero THEN
            -- do nothing, just repeat the loop
          WHEN deadlock_detected THEN
            -- do nothing, just repeat the loop
        END;
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    RAISE INFO 'Finished.';

    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: +1 For this example exception handling wouldn't be necessary, but for other cases like you mentioned (deadlock and such) you make good use of exception handling combined with the extra loop.

Answer (score 4):

For what you are trying to do, a [**LOOP inside the LOOP**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS) would be a proper solution. No need for expensive exception handling.

Test setup:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE usr (id int, dummy text);
INSERT INTO usr VALUES
 (1,'foo')
,(2,'bar')
,(3,'baz')
,(4,'blarg');
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION x.foo()
  RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    _r          record;
    _dummy      integer := 0;
    _ct         integer := 0;
    _5mod_ct    integer;
BEGIN
    RAISE INFO 'Start... ';
    FOR _r IN
        SELECT * FROM usr WHERE id < 50 LIMIT 10
    LOOP
        LOOP
            UPDATE usr SET dummy = 'foo' WHERE id = _r.id;

            _ct      := _ct + 1;
            _5mod_ct := 5 % _ct;

            EXIT WHEN _5mod_ct > 0; -- make sure this will be TRUE eventually!
            RAISE INFO '_5mod_ct = 0; repeating UPDATE!';
        END LOOP;

        _dummy := 10 / _5mod_ct;
        RAISE NOTICE '_5mod_ct: %, _dummy: %, user.id: %',
                      _5mod_ct, _dummy, _r.id;
    END LOOP;
    RAISE INFO 'Finished.';
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT foo()
```

Output:

```
INFO:  Start...
INFO:  _5mod_ct = 0; repeating UPDATE!
NOTICE:  _5mod_ct: 1, _dummy: 10, user.id: 1
NOTICE:  _5mod_ct: 2, _dummy: 5, user.id: 2
NOTICE:  _5mod_ct: 1, _dummy: 10, user.id: 3
INFO:  _5mod_ct = 0; repeating UPDATE!
NOTICE:  _5mod_ct: 5, _dummy: 2, user.id: 4
INFO:  Finished.
```

Your code example displays a number of problems:

- Don't use **reserved words** as identifiers. `user` is a [reserved word in every SQL standard and in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in particular. It is bad practice to call your table "user". The double-quotes make it possible. Doesn't mean it's a good idea, though.
- Don't declare variables of the same name as table columns you use in the function body. That leads to naming conflicts very easily. `dummy` is a variable and a column name at the same time in your example. Just another loaded foot gun. One (arbitrary) possibility is to prefix variables with a `_` like I demonstrate.
- A [`FOR` loop](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) like I demonstrate is much simpler than explicit cursor handling.

Comment: Thanx for useful advices, but I need to handle exceptions, I used 'division by zero' just like a test. On production server I have to handle dead lock exceptions and others. But thank you anyway, I've used your's suggestions in my solution below.